# How to query posts that have certain post meta keys, and sort by meta key and/or value

Tags: custom-field, lists

I'm using this structure to make album lists. I'm using a key so I correspond lists to albums but I don't know how to reverse the output so the items start at the top with lowest key value. Any ideas?

```
  <?php
 $album = get_post_meta($post->ID, "album", false);
 $album_list = get_post_meta($post->ID, "album_list", false); 
 foreach ($album_list as $album_list) {
     list($key, $value) = explode(',',$album_list);
     $indexed_album_list[$key] = $value;
 }
 foreach ( $album as $each_album) {
     list($key,$album) = explode(',',$each_album);
     echo '<div>'.$album.'</div>';
     echo '<div>';
     if ($album_list = $indexed_album_list[$key]) {
         echo $album_list;
     }  
     else {
         echo '&nbsp';
     }
     echo '</div>';
 }
?>
```

Comment: What is stored in the `album` and `album_list` post meta?

Comment: This is a **PHP** question, not a **WordPress** question.

Comment: I use a key like "001,album" and "002,album" with "001,album_list", "002,album_list". I know it's php but wordpress is php and I'm making this widget with wordpress.

Comment: "*I know it's php but wordpress is php and I'm making this widget with wordpress*" - that doesn't make this question *in-scope*. You're talking about how to manipulate arrays, which is a **PHP** function. It doesn't matter that the array was returned by WordPress. Now, if you re-worded the question, to ask, e.g. *how to query posts that have certain post meta keys, and sort by meta key and/or value*, then *that* very much *would* be in-scope for WPSE.

Comment: Touche =) ...For what it's worth I asked the question on Stackoverflow in both the chat and with a post and didn't get an answer.

Comment: Great! :) Now, back to @m0r7if3r's comment/question above, as it will be the key to answering your question: what data are returned by your `get_post_meta()` calls for `album` and `album_list`?

Comment: Also, do you actually need to *query posts*? Or is this in the context  of a given post?

Comment: `foreach ($album_list as $album_list)` – you’re asking for trouble. Make the first one a plural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about array_reverse()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php

there are a bunch of array manipulation functions at php.net.  i'm always there looking something up.  also sort() might be useful

**EDIT** based on your comments:

```
sort($album);
print_r($album);
```

should return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 001,Get Rich Or Die Tryin
    [1] => 002,Curtis
    [2] => 003,The Massacre
    [3] => 004,Before I Self Destruct
)
```

Comment: Right now the order shows the album that I entered from first to last and doesn't go by the keys. I think array_reverse would just change the order by which I entered in the albums. Am I wrong?

Comment: what does your array look like?  can you print_r() it?  and try some of the sort() functions.

Comment: We need to see your *returned data*, in order to give you a more precise answer.

Comment: Where do I add print_r() to do that? Every example I find on how to use sort doesnt look anything like the structure I have. I'm really just trying to make it say "asc by order of $key"

Comment: $album = get_post_meta($post->ID, "album", false); print_r($album);
 $album_list = get_post_meta($post->ID, "album_list", false); print_r($album_list);      really hard to help you more w/o seeing how your data is set up

Comment: Ok thx for workin with me. Heres what it returned for 4 albums I entered. `Array ( [0] => 002,Curtis [1] => 001,Get Rich Or Die Tryin [2] => 003,The Massacre [3] => 004,Before I Self Destruct ) Array ( [0] => 001, [1] => 002, [2] => 003, [3] => 004,`

Comment: Yeap lol..just added the sort($album) and it worked. Sorry for not knowing what I'm doing and making that complicated. Thx for your help!

Comment: If this answer solved your issue, then you should **accept** it, by clicking the checkmark beneath the vote count.